# pdfLaTeX does not compile

Tags: miktex, texmaker

I have Texmaker with MiKTeX 2.9.

When I tried to run simple code with quick build ("PDFLaTeX + View PDF") such as

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

it starts compiling for hours with no output until I terminated.

What is the problem with it?

Here are my settings:

[image: settings screenshot]

Comment: It should probably be `\documentclass[11pt]{article}`, but I guess that was just a typo? What is the Quick build settings? What if you compile with pdfLaTeX (shortcut F6)?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes sorry pt was a type mistake. Quick build is PdfLatex+view PDF. F6 gives the same result

Comment: run at [commandline window](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/open-a-command-prompt-window) `cd Desktop` and `pdflatex sample2e` to verify the installation.

Comment: @texenthusiast it shows 'This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)'

Comment: Did you get the `sample2e.pdf` finally on `Desktop` ?. Settings look normal. What is the `.log` file saying and what is the Texmaker status showing in bottom ? BTW did you press `Stop process` button at bottom and Restarted `Quick Build` again. `Only in Emergency`: backup the Settings File by `options`>`Settings File`-->`Save a copy of Settings File` and `Reset Settings` by going to `Options`--> `Settings File`-->Reset Settings and Restart Texmaker.

Comment: If this is still a problem I'd try reinstalling MikTeX, or trying TeX Live instead.